# Automatically update CGRect based on changing value of CGFloat

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgrect

I have a variable `CGFloat x` in my view controller. I created a frame with this variable:

```
CGRectMake(x,x,4*x,4*x)
```

When `x` is changed, I want the value of frame to also change without any manual updating.
How can I do that?

Comment: CGFloat is not mutable (it's not even a real object as it decomposes to a primitive type). There is no point to make a "deep copy" of it. The question likely goes something like: "How can I make a CGRect that dynamically changes (based on a variable)?"

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to 'deep copy' a `CGFloat`, since `CGFloat` is a **primitive type**, not an object. Additionally, `CGRect` is a `struct`, not an object, so it consists of 4 `CGFloat`s stored one after the other. Not references to `CGFloat`s, but the **raw values** themselves.

However, if you declare `x` as a property of your view controller:

```
@property CGFloat x;
```

Then you can override the setter of `x` to update the value of your frame:

```
- (void)setX:(CGFloat)x {
    _x = x;
    self.myFrame = CGRectMake(x, x, x * 4, x * 4);
}
```

In this way, every time you change `x` using `self.x = whatever`, the setter method will be called and your frame will be updated.

This is basically the safest and most reliable way to do this, as long as you remember to ***only* set `x` by `self.x = whatever`**, if you set the underlying ivar `_x` directly, the setter will not be called and the frame won't  update.

Comment: thank you for your answer. but if there are around 50 uiviews with different frames, then how can we set frame for each?

Comment: Have an array of all your `UIView`s and loop through it to set the frame for each one.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a copy of Immutable data.So you can't make a copy CGFloat.But if you wanna change your frame in that case you need to set your frame in setter method of X property.